# OpenGraph Fadcebook - How to configure the app to post to my Facebook group

Tags: facebook-opengraph

Good morning,
I created an app that allows me to post to my groups.
However, I encounter a problem. I have this error:
{
"error": {
"message": "(#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and 
either publish_to_groups both permission with user token, or pages_read_engagement 
and pages_manage_posts permission with page token; If posting to a page, 
requires both pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts as an admin with 
sufficient administrative permission",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 200,
"fbtrace_id": "AheiAYnYgKKV1i_YdBaFzYK"
}
}

I don't want to publish my app because it's for personal use.
The app is online and I have all the authorizations
I am a group administrator
Can you help me ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXGxT.png)

I tried to see if it came from permissions but no.
I think it's because the app is not attached to the group, but as the app is not published, I can't attach it.
I looked at the doc and I can't find how to use the app only personally

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.